# Linq Group By multiple properties in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-entities

I want to Group By on a List using VB.Net.  Seems simple but I can't make it work.  I've tried:

```
Dim groupedEmails = saEmails.GroupBy(Function(m) New With {m.Property1, m.Property2, m.Property3.SubProperty1})
```

I have 6 items in saEmails and two of the items have the same Property1, Property2 and Property3. Unfortunately, at runtime I'm still getting 6 items in groupedEmails even though my grouping should reduce that count to 5.

I've tried the statement without the "New With" (it still compiles) but the result is the same.  I also can't get Linq to Entities ("From mail in saEmails...") to accept my use of the keyword "Group".  I have **Import**ed System.Linq.

I would also be happy with a working use of .ToLookup().

The entities are similar to this:

```
    Namespace Something
    <DataContract()>
    Public Class SAEmail

        <DataMember()>
        Public Property Property1 As Integer

        <DataMember()>
        Public Property Property2 As String

        <DataMember()>
        Public Property Property3 As Blah

        <DataMember()>
        Public Property Property4 As String

    Public Overrides Function Equals(obj As Object) As Boolean

        If obj Is Nothing OrElse Not Me.GetType() Is obj.GetType() Then
            Return False
        End If

        Dim email As SAEmail = CType(obj, SAEmail)
        Return Property1 = email.Property1 _
            AndAlso Property2 = email.Property2 _
            AndAlso Property1.SubProperty1 = email.Property3.SubProperty1

    End Function

    Public Overrides Function GetHashCode() As Integer
        Return CInt(CLng(Property1) Xor CLng(Property2) Xor CLng(Property3.SubProperty1))
    End Function

    End Class

    <DataContract()>
    Public Class Blah

        <DataMember()>
        Public Property SubProperty1 As Integer

        <DataMember()>
        Public Property SubProperty2 As String

    End Class
End Namespace
```

Ideas?

Comment: Can you post the definition of `saEmails` and its class?

Comment: Post the data in your collection in Property1, Property2, SubProperty1

Comment: I don't expect this to be an issue with why your grouping isn't working, but your implementation of the class is wrong. You can **not** compute `GetHashCode` using the values of read/write properties. The value produced by `GetHashCode` **must not change** throughout the lifetime of the instance of the object.

Comment: @Enigmativity, I followed Microsoft's example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336aedhh(v=vs.100).aspx.  Is that invalid?

Comment: @Dewey - Microsoft's example is ok because the classes don't have mutable properties and none of the fields change. Have a read of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx and look at the "Notes to inheritors" - in particular about immutability.

Comment: @Dewey - Also look at this - http://ericlippert.com/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about creating a composite grouping key?

```
Dim groupedEmails = saEmails.GroupBy(Function(m) String.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", m.Property1, m.Property2, m.Property3.SubProperty1))
```

Or, using an interpolated string when VB14 is released in a few weeks!:

```
Dim groupedEmails = saEmails.GroupBy(Function(m) $"{m.Property1}:{m.Property2}:{m.Property3.SubProperty1)}")
```